# Is it possible to execute javascript through Wagtail's richtext field?

Tags: django, web, content-management-system, wagtail

I was building a website with django and wagtail as cms, I was wondering if it's possible to execute javascript through wagtail's richtext field with wagtail's default richtext filter.

For example, add a onclick attribute to a link.

My goal is to prevent such thing from happening, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The `|richtext` template filter does not strip out any Javascript code (such as `onclick` attributes or `<script>` tags) from its input - it only performs light rewriting of [Wagtail's internal HTML-like format](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/rich_text_internals.html), such as replacing `<a linktype="page" id="123">` page references with real URLs.

However, Javascript code *is* blocked at the point of submission through the Draftail rich text editor. This is because data is prepared and submitted in a non-HTML format (namely [Draft.JS ContentState JSON](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/how-draft-js-represents-rich-text-data-eeabb5f25cf2)) and then converted to Wagtail's HTML-like format when saving to the database - in this process, there is an 'allowed list' of elements to be converted, and none of these have any provision for passing Javascript code. (If a way to bypass this mechanism were discovered, then this would be considered a security issue and handled through [Wagtail's security process](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/contributing/security.html).)

This does mean that if your project inserts untrusted rich text data into the database in a way that *doesn't* go through the rich text editor (such as importing content from an external source), it's your responsibility to validate that data for any unwanted elements / attributes.